# VC++ missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++, visual-studio, types, compiler-errors

Following code compiled perfectly fine in VC++ 6.0, but when I opened the project in VS2005, I get this error:

> BCGPopupMenu.h(100): error C4430: missing type specifier - int
>   assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

What could be the problem ?

```
class BCGCONTROLBARDLLEXPORT CBCGPopupMenu : public CMiniFrameWnd
{
public:
    enum ANIMATION_TYPE
    {
        NO_ANIMATION,
        UNFOLD,
        SLIDE,
        FADE
    };

static SetAnimationType (CBCGPopupMenu::ANIMATION_TYPE type)
    {
        m_AnimationType = type; // this line gives error
    }
protected:
    static ANIMATION_TYPE m_AnimationType;

};
```

Comment: This is probably going to get closed as duplicate but "SetAnimationType" has no return type. If you don't return anything the return type is void. Just add void after static.

Comment: thanks. But I wonder how it worked on earlier versions.

Comment: The answer is in the error message: `... Note: C++ does not support default-int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static SetAnimationType (CBCGPopupMenu::ANIMATION_TYPE type)
```

there is no return value,you should do:

```
static void SetAnimationType (CBCGPopupMenu::ANIMATION_TYPE type)
```

Answer (score -2):

One possible reason is missing definitions. When you switch IDE, make sure you add every path you need into project setting.

See Tools >> Options >> Projects and Solutions >> VC++ Directories

Comment: Not the case here. SetAnimationType has no return type.

Comment: @Borgleader Of course, missing return type is an error here. I'm just trying to remind, it's good to check path setting in VS when seeing missing type specifier error.